# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. - When using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I am building a Blog App in react and I am trying to send argument to another functional component and Also trying to use `useState` to set state when call, But When I click on button to send argument then, `Argument is successfully working (sending to component)` but `State is not setting` through `useState`.

It is showing error every time I define `useState`.

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I have tried many times but it is still not working.

App.js

```
function App() {

   const sendArgument = () => {
     AnotherComponent("argument_1")
   }

   return (
     <div>

        <button type="button" onClick={sendArgument}>Send Argument</button>


     </div>
   )
}

function AnotherComponent(arg_1) {
   // Error shows when I define useState here...
   const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

   // Argument is successfully showing
   console.log(arg_1)
   // Set to true when fucntional component calls from another component
   setIsOpen(true)

   const setBooleanTrue = () => {
     setIsOpen(false)

   }

   return (
   <div>

   <button type="button" onClick={setBooleanTrue}>Set state</button>


   </div>
   )
}
```

It is keep showing that error, and not setting state, when I remove `useState` then error is not showing.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance

Comment: In React we don't invoke React functions directly, we express them in JSX and React handles calling the transpiled function within the confines of the React component lifecycle. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot call a hook inside a nested function which is what is happening since AnotherComponent is inside the sendArgument function.

You can render anotherComponent inside the return function of App Component itself. Define the state in the App component itself and send it to AnotherComponent as prop.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: I also think, I should do it as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the state inside the nested component/function.
I don't have a exact context of your code but based on your code snippet
Here i have refactored your code.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [argToSend, setArgToSend] = useState();

  const sendArgument = () => {
    setArgToSend("Some Argument");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={sendArgument}>
        Send Argument
      </button>
      <AnotherComponent arg={argToSend} />
    </div>
  );
}

function AnotherComponent({ arg }) {
  // Another component's own state
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const setBooleanTrue = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>
        Argument received from Another component:-
        <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{arg}</span>
      </h4>
      <h3>{isOpen ? "True" : "False"}</h3>
      <button type="button" onClick={setBooleanTrue}>
        Set state
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As suggested by Parth you should send data from a component to another as props
Also I would suggest you to use any code formatter
Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: `AnotherComponent` is rendering permanently, I don't want to return the component `return data`

Comment: Can you please tell exact requirement?
I guess if you want ```AnotherComponent``` to render only when you pass something to it then conditionally rendering it will be a way.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, You're right, I want to render only when I pass something and I will turn a `boolean to true` when `AnotherComponent` is rendering and when user click on cancel button then I will turn `boolean to false` and return of `AnotherComponent` disappears

Comment: A simple conditional rendering inside ```AnotherComponent ``` will do the job.
Pass the props ```true```or ```false``` to ```AnotherComponent``` and render it's content only when it is true.

Comment: But it is rendering forever when defined